# Tkinter: How to get a variable from a radiobutton, when using the grid geometry manager

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm new to Tkinter and I've been trying to `get` a variable from a radio button, when using the `grid` geometry manager.

I know when you use `pack()`, you can use `variable.get()`, however I'm using `grid()` with a function within a class, with `self`.

Could someone possibly show me an example, I've tried searching around, but no luck.

Comment: grid and pack have nothing to do with the problem. In both cases you use `variable.get()`. We'll have to see your code to help you.

Comment: see [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_radiobutton.htm) example. this should get you started. `grid` or `pack` don't matter at all in this regard